# How to integrate $\frac{x+3}{(6-x^2)^\frac32}$?

Tags: integration

As the title shows, how to calculate the integral: 
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{x+3}{(6-x^2)^\frac32}dx$$

Comment: You're sure the exponent is $\frac{2}{3}$ and not $\frac{3}{2}$ in which case you would try a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{x}{(6-x^2)^\frac{2}{3}}$ is an odd function so that part of the integral is zero over the interval $[-1,1]$ which leaves only the $\dfrac{3}{(6-x^2)^\frac{2}{3}}$ which is even.

Comment: This looks like a rather hard integral, precisely because of the exponent.

Comment: You are expected to show your own attempts at answering your question and explain in more detail what you have tried.  This is not a site for simply asking questions and expecting free answers.

Comment: @heropup, I know the rule. I indeed try several ways to sovle this problem, chaning the element, find the odd term x. Using python and matlab symbolic operation. While This is a mathematical question instead of a tech one, giving the imformation as concise as I can should be the principle. Stating what I have tried in a concise math question is not a good idea for me. I will state what I have done in an answer from myself. Thanks.

Comment: @ZHI That is not how this site works, and that is why one of the options provided to voters who vote to close a question is "Off topic" (for lack of context).  Educate yourself on the community guidelines before claiming that the site should follow your principles rather than those already established.

Comment: From the tour of the site:  "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. **Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.**"  (Emphasis mine)

Comment: @heropup, you're right, I will pay attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the substitution $\; x=\sqrt 6\sin t$.

Comment: The final expression turns out to be surprisingly nice.